# angularjs - How do I store an array inside sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, session-storage

I am developing a website using HTML5 and AngularJS, and inside the controller I access the database and initialize an array `$scope.array`.

Afterwards I save the initialized array in the session:

```
sessionStorage.array = $scope.array;
```

If that array exists in the sessionStorage, I want to load the sessionStorage copy, and not define an empty array.

I do it like so:

```
if(sessionStorage.array)
        $scope.array = sessionStorage.array;
else
        $scope.array = [];
```

So that `$scope.array` is the array I present to the HTML via `ng-repeat`.

But my problem is that after refreshing for the first time, the `$scope.array` object becomes an empty array (Before refreshing, it was initialized with values from the database)

How can I save the array in the session so that it won't get to the 'else' branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want

```
var arr = sessionStorage.getItem("array");
$scope.array = arr ? JSON.parse(arr) : [];
```

...

```
sessionStorage.setItem("array",JSON.stringify($scope.array));
```

Comment: this example is working correctly for storing and getting data using sessionStorage